# Regex unique this not that query needed

Tags: regex

At work we're using a unique system that allows us to choose a delimiter of our choice to separate and list data.

The issue we're having is one of the teams wants `|$|` to be used which is an issue because the function is meant to only accept one character as a delimiter, not three. So as the data comes in, our system is separating anything with a `|` sign in the data. So the team is sending us something that looks like the following:

Data log:
`000123|$|000124|$|000125|000126|$|000127...`

The third set in this string has two integers in it. This is not very common, but when it does it can throw off an account with THOUSANDS of these sets in it. I know how to perform a simple find this, but I'm dealing with something a littler more complex. **I'd like to be able to search for "| but not when it's specifically written like |$|" in regex**

If the account has `000124|$99.99`, that's still a valid time to replace the | with it's HTML counterpart.

The second part to this is that the `$` is in the same boat, but I'd assume the search part I'm dealing with is modestly the same query.

Comment: Is it for JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a negative lookbehind, and a negative lookahead. This will work, assuming PCRE

```
/(?<!\|\$)\|(?!\$\|)/
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/nXhhuA/1

Comment: If negative lookbehind for some reason isn't supported, you can also use `[^\|\$]\|[^\$]`: https://regex101.com/r/nXhhuA/2, which should be a bit more portable, and then modify the second matched character. (Thanks for pointing out this site, Chris!) It says "match something that's not a pipe or a dollar sign, followed by a pipe, followed by something that's not a dollar sign." It won't work if a single pipe starts or ends the string, but I don't think you'll run into that, from your description.